# Using a web server to control an arduino

Tags: node.js, arduino

I'm using node.js and Johnny five in order to control an arduino over the network.
I'm trying to make the light on the arduino turn on when the client clicks on a button in his browser. I figured out I should probably use the socket.io module to do so.. Anyone knows how to do it...?? I found this guy that did it using a narf module. Is it necessary?

Thanks!

Comment: First link on google search: http://semu.github.io/noduino/ . If you need more specific information, I would suggest you write a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either connect via RS232 to arduino. I don't know wheter this is possible at all from node.js. The other option is to put a ethernet shield on your arduino, implement a simple web service and call this from node.js.

With the second option it's just calling an URL to connect to the arduino.